# System-Overlaying Keylistener in java

Tags: java, focus, overlay, keylistener

Is there a way to create a keylistener in Java that works outside of the program-window itself? I want it to run all the time and if you press a certain button / combination it will execute some lines of code, no matter which window you are in.
Does Java have this capability?

Comment: No, this cannot be done with core Java without using some access to native code such as JNI or JNA. Myself, I'd use a utility that is built for this, such as AutoIt if for the Windows platform. This can even be meshed in with a Java program using sockets if desired, and in fact I've done this.

Comment: I guessed so. I will definitiv try out the AutoIt way since it doesn't sound as complicated as the native programming. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, here's something I've found quite a while ago and it made me think about this question again:

[JNativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) is a library that allows you to listen for system-wide keyevents with Java.

Here's some sample [code](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Keyboard) from their [github](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) to implement a simple key-listener:

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
}
```